# Shipment Email in Automation Notifications

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone has any idea how can I have email from Shipment Settings tab on Shipment Screen (SO302000) on Automation Notifications screen (SM205040) under Emails dropdown/lookup on Addresses tab. Please refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

I did not find any code which I customize or if there is any DB table I need to populate. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need, create DAC Extension for main DAC of primary view (here `Shipment`) and declare an unbound user-field depending on out-of-box `SOShipment.ShipContactID` and decorated with `PXSelector`.

```c
public class SOShipmentPXExt : PXCacheExtension<SOShipment>
{
    public abstract class usrShipContactID : IBqlField { };

    [PXInt()]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<SOShipmentContact.contactID>))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ship Contact", Enabled = false, Visible = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
    [PXDependsOnFields(typeof(SOShipment.shipContactID))]
    public int? UsrShipContactID
    {
        get
        {
            return Base.ShipContactID;
        }
    }
}
```

And add this field on Shipment Entry Page

[image]

After publishing above change, you should be able to use this field in Automation Notifications (SM205040)

[image]